# Override automatically generated max-width CSS rule in Wordpress Enfold

Tags: html, css, wordpress

My Wordpress theme (Enfold) is automatically generating a CSS file. One of the rules generated is:

```
.responsive .container {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

If I delete this line from the automatically generated CSS, it achieves my desired result but it will then revert to the original every time a style change is made in the Wordpress Admin area.

The normal way to override this would be a rule in the 'custom.css' file. 
I have tried adding this in the custom.css file, but it does not do anything:

```
.responsive .container {
        max-width: none;
    }
```

In the developer tools panel in Chrome, if I add some nonsense like `max-width: xxxxx` then this will have the desired effect of cancelling out the theme's rule. Adding the nonsense to the 'custom.css' file does not work.

Is there a way of overriding one CSS rule with another which is undefined?

In pseudo-CSS I guess want to say `max-width: 'ignore everything'`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use !important

```
.responsive .container {
    max-width: none !important;
}
```

Comment: No, that does not work. The rule is not being overwritten by another, but it is ineffectual.

Comment: Sorry, now I understand your problem... based on my knowledges I think there's not a solution with pure css. You should understand how wordpress calculate the fixed max-width (in my case I see 1010px) and set it as inline style

Comment: I think that max-width is always 1010px... so you can set `max-width: 1010px !important`

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
.responsive .container, .container {
  max-width: none !important;
}
```